# Make sequence diagram of class diagram with composition

Tags: sequence-diagram

I want to improve my diagramming skills and I have made a class diagram where
a **Teacher** can create **Announcement** in a **classroom**.
**Announcement** has composition with **File** class and **file** has children **VideoFile** and **DocumentFile**,
where documents can be pdfs or images.
Now I don't understand message 4 or less 5 is the right way to do it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a sequence diagram, you show messages or other operations between objects (such as actors or processes). This means that these objects must be able to send or receive these messages or respectively perform and process the corresponding function calls.

I am not quite sure which elements of you model are the acting objects and which elements are data content for the operations.

So you might start with the following:

- Can you upload a file to a *VideoFile* object? (probably not)
- Can you upload a file to an *Announcement* object? Is *Announcement* a class
  with methods or is it really itself a data structure?
- Which one is the process that adds an entry to the database? Is it the *Teacher* (e.g. via a user interface) or is it the *Announcement* class?

Hope this helps.